# Stripe Payment API integration to Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, stripe-payments, android-jetpack-compose

I can't figure it out, how to impalement Stripe API integration into an Compose app

Here is Stripe provided snippet of code

```
    class CheckoutActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  lateinit var paymentSheet: PaymentSheet

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    paymentSheet = PaymentSheet(this, ::onPaymentSheetResult)
  }

  fun onPaymentSheetResult(paymentSheetResult: PaymentSheetResult) {
    // implemented in the next steps
  }
}
```

In my case I am out of ideas where to put **paymentSheet = PaymentSheet(this, ::onPaymentSheetResult)** in compose code as it shows that:
*None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied*.

*(ComponentActivity, PaymentSheetResultCallback) defined in com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.PaymentSheet*

*(Fragment, PaymentSheetResultCallback) defined in com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.PaymentSheet*

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    lateinit var paymentSheet: PaymentSheet
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            PayTheme {
                LoginUi()
            }
        }

        fun onPaymentSheetResult(paymentSheetResult: PaymentSheetResult) {
            // implemented in the next steps
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can check the stripe compose sample on github [stripe-android (ComposeExampleActivity.kt)](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/stripe/example/activity/ComposeExampleActivity.kt).

#### Add stripe dependency

`implementation "com.stripe:stripe-android:20.17.0"`

#### Initialize stripe `PaymentConfiguration` in the Application class

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidApp
class BookstoreApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        PaymentConfiguration.init(applicationContext, BuildConfig.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY)
    }
}
```

Stripe provides many ways to implement payments in the app. Let's consider payment confirmation using `PaymentSheetContract` and `PaymentLauncher`.

#### Example #1: Confirm payment using `PaymentSheetContract`

In this case, we should use `rememberLauncherForActivityResult()` with `PaymentSheetContract()` to launch stripe payment form.

**PaymentScreen.kt (Compose)**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PaymentScreen(
    viewModel: PaymentViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val stripeLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = PaymentSheetContract(),
        onResult = {
            viewModel.handlePaymentResult(it)
        }
    )
    val clientSecret by viewModel.clientSecret.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    clientSecret?.let {
        val args = PaymentSheetContract.Args.createPaymentIntentArgs(it)
        stripeLauncher.launch(args)
        viewModel.onPaymentLaunched()
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                viewModel.makePayment()
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Confirm payment")
        }
    }
}
```

**PaymentViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class PaymentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PaymentRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _clientSecret = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    val clientSecret = _clientSecret.asStateFlow()

    fun makePayment() {
        val paymentIntent = repository.createPaymentIntent()
        _clientSecret.update { paymentIntent.clientSecret }
    }

    fun onPaymentLaunched() {
        _clientSecret.update { null }
    }

    fun handlePaymentResult(result: PaymentSheetResult) {
        when(result) {
            PaymentSheetResult.Canceled -> TODO()
            PaymentSheetResult.Completed -> TODO()
            is PaymentSheetResult.Failed -> TODO()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example #2: Confirm payment using `PaymentLauncher`

In this case, we should use `rememberLauncherForActivityResult()` with `PaymentSheetContract()` to launch stripe payment form.

**PaymentScreen.kt (Compose)**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PaymentScreen(
    viewModel: PaymentViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val paymentLauncher = rememberPaymentLauncher(viewModel::handlePaymentResult)
    val confirmPaymentParams by viewModel.confirmPaymentParams.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    confirmPaymentParams?.let { payment ->
        paymentLauncher.confirm(payment)
        viewModel.onPaymentLaunched()
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                viewModel.makePayment()
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Confirm payment")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberPaymentLauncher(
    callback: PaymentLauncher.PaymentResultCallback
): PaymentLauncher {
    val config = PaymentConfiguration.getInstance(LocalContext.current)
    return PaymentLauncher.rememberLauncher(
        publishableKey = config.publishableKey,
        stripeAccountId = config.stripeAccountId,
        callback = callback
    )
}
```

**PaymentViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class PaymentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PaymentRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _confirmPaymentParams = MutableStateFlow<ConfirmPaymentIntentParams?>(null)
    val confirmPaymentParams = _confirmPaymentParams.asStateFlow()

    fun makePayment() {
        val paymentIntent = repository.createPaymentIntent()
        // For example, pay with hardcoded test card
        val configuration = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(
            paymentMethodCreateParams = PaymentMethodCreateParams.create(
                card = PaymentMethodCreateParams.Card(
                    number = "4242424242424242",
                    expiryMonth = 1,
                    expiryYear = 24,
                    cvc = "111"
                )
            ),
            clientSecret = paymentIntent.clientSecret
        )
        _confirmPaymentParams.update { configuration }
    }

    fun onPaymentLaunched() {
        _confirmPaymentParams.update { null }
    }

    fun handlePaymentResult(result: PaymentResult) {
        when(result) {
            PaymentResult.Canceled -> TODO()
            PaymentResult.Completed -> TODO()
            is PaymentResult.Failed -> TODO()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Data layer

The functions described below should be implemented somewhere on the server side. So, the client should only request some data from **payment intent** (`client_secret` for example).

Please, read stripe [Accept a payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet) doc to understand better.
You can also watch youtube video: [How to integrate Stripe in Android Studio 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h12wNuOher4).

**PaymentRepository.kt**

```kotlin
class PaymentRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val stripeApiService: StripeApiService,
    private val paymentDao: PaymentDao
) {
    /*
        Create customer before payment (attach to app user)
     */
    suspend fun createCustomer() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val customer = stripeApiService.createCustomer()
        // save customer in the database or preferences
        // customerId required to confirm payment
        paymentDao.insertCustomer(customer)
    }

    suspend fun refreshCustomerEphemeralKey() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val customer = paymentDao.getCustomer()
        val key = stripeApiService.createEphemeralKey(customer.customerId)
        paymentDao.insertEphemeralKey(key)
    }

    suspend fun createPaymentIntent() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val customer = paymentDao.getCustomer()
        refreshCustomerEphemeralKey()
        val paymentIntent = stripeApiService.createPaymentIntent(
            customerId = customer.customerId,
            amount = 1000,
            currency = "usd", // or your currency
            autoPaymentMethodsEnable = true
        )
        return@withContext paymentIntent
    }
}
```

**StripeApiService.kt**

```kotlin
private const val SECRET = BuildConfig.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

interface StripeApiService {

    @Headers(
        "Authorization: Bearer $SECRET",
        "Stripe-Version: 2022-08-01"
    )
    @POST("v1/customers")
    suspend fun createCustomer() : CustomerApiModel

    @Headers(
        "Authorization: Bearer $SECRET",
        "Stripe-Version: 2022-08-01"
    )
    @POST("v1/ephemeral_keys")
    suspend fun createEphemeralKey(
        @Query("customer") customerId: String
    ): EphemeralKeyApiModel

    @Headers(
        "Authorization: Bearer $SECRET"
    )
    @POST("v1/payment_intents")
    suspend fun createPaymentIntent(
        @Query("customer") customerId: String,
        @Query("amount") amount: Int,
        @Query("currency") currency: String,
        @Query("automatic_payment_methods[enabled]") autoPaymentMethodsEnable: Boolean,
    ): PaymentIntentApiModel

}
```

Comment: Sorry, for my late response. I have a question about 'PaymentRepository', is it being declared by adding stripe library or I should declare by myself as it is currently unresolved?

Comment: @Tomee Of course, you should create your own repository. I have added a "sample code" for PaymentRepository. 
As I described in the answer, you should only request payment intent from the backend. If you develop a sample project, you can implement this stripe logic in the android app (in repository for example)

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly kudos to the accepted answer given by @lincollincol above, very detailed and efficient.**

But, starting from Stripe SDK version "20.26.0" doing it via both the methods in accepted answer is **not suggested and also not required** for doing it in **compose**.

Because both **`PaymentSheetContract`** and **`PaymentLauncher`** has been **deprecated** and will be removed in future from the SDK itself.

Instead now we can use `rememberPaymentSheet()` directly in our Compose method.
Here's how

**STEP 1:- Initalizing the "PaymentSheet" in my compose screen and setting up Checkout ViewModel**

```
@Composable
fun CheckoutScreen(
    checkoutVM: CheckoutVM = hiltViewModel(),
) {
val context = LocalContext.current
val checkoutState = checkoutVM.checkoutState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

val paymentSheet =
    rememberPaymentSheet(paymentResultCallback = checkoutVM::onPaymentSheetResult)

LaunchedEffect(key1 = checkoutState.value.paymentSheetResult, block = {

    when (checkoutState.value.paymentSheetResult) {
        is PaymentSheetResult.Canceled -> {}
        is PaymentSheetResult.Completed -> {}
        is PaymentSheetResult.Failed -> {}
        null -> {}
    }

})

LaunchedEffect(key1 = checkoutState.value.checkoutSessionDM, block = {
//        If Checkout DM is not null hence the Payment Details are successfully fetched,
//        then show the Stripe Payment Sheet

    checkoutState.value.checkoutSessionDM?.run {
//            Present the Stripe payment sheet
        checkoutVM.onEvent(CheckoutEvent.OnCheckOut(paymentSheet))
    }
})

Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Text(modifier = Modifier.clickable {
        //Performs a Server Side request to get the Stripe PaymentSheet required parameters
        checkoutVM.onEvent(CheckoutEvent.OnInitPayment(paymentSheet))

    }, text = "Checkout Screen")
}

}
```

In above code I am getting the payment sheet via

```
    val paymentSheet =
    rememberPaymentSheet(paymentResultCallback = checkoutVM::onPaymentSheetResult)
```

**Callback Method :**  For the callback I've passed a method defined in my Checkout ViewModel called `onPaymentSheetResult(paymentSheetResult: PaymentSheetResult)`

> Callback can also be handled in the composable, using **LaunchedEffect** and observing the state change as shown above.
> You can choose whatever fits your code architecture

All the events are handled in my Hilt ViewModel called **"CheckoutVM"**.
On Clicking the TextComp I call my Server Side API to fetch Payment Details or Payment sheet required parameters values
Like clientSecret or publishable key etc.

I am passing my `paymentSheet` instance to `checkoutVM` viewModel using on the `onEvent()` method.

Here's the code for my **CheckoutVM**

```
 @HiltViewModel
class CheckoutVM @Inject constructor(
    private val checkoutRepoDec: CheckoutRepoDec,
) : ViewModel() {

private val _checkoutState = MutableStateFlow(CheckoutState())
val checkoutState: StateFlow<CheckoutState> = _checkoutState


fun onEvent(event: CheckoutEvent) {
    when (event) {
        is CheckoutEvent.OnInitPayment -> {
            getPaymentSessionDetails(event)
        }

        is CheckoutEvent.OnCheckOut -> {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                checkoutRepoDec.presentPaymentSheet(event.paymentSheet)
            }
        }

    }

}

private fun getPaymentSessionDetails(event: CheckoutEvent.OnInitPayment) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        checkoutRepoDec.initPaymentSheet(event.paymentSheet)?.collect { result ->

            when (result) {
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    _checkoutState.update {
                        it.copy(
                            checkoutSessionDM = null,
                            checkoutSessionError = result.error
                        )
                    }
                }

                is Resource.Loading -> {
                   _checkoutState.update {
                       it.copy(isLoading = result.isLoading)
                   }
                }

                is Resource.Success -> {
                    _checkoutState.update {
                        it.copy(
                            checkoutSessionDM = result.data,
                            checkoutSessionError = null
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

fun onPaymentSheetResult(paymentSheetResult: PaymentSheetResult) {

//        To Handle the response using "LaunchedEffect" in my Checkout Screen Composable
    _checkoutState.update {
        it.copy(
            paymentSheetResult = paymentSheetResult
        )
    }

//        To handle it here in Checkout ViewModel
    when (paymentSheetResult) {
        is PaymentSheetResult.Canceled -> {
            showLog(TAG, "paymentSheetResult - Canceled")

        }

        is PaymentSheetResult.Failed -> {
            showLog(TAG, "paymentSheetResult - Error: ${paymentSheetResult.error}")
        }

        is PaymentSheetResult.Completed -> {
            // Display for example, an order confirmation screen
            showLog(TAG, "paymentSheetResult - Completed")
        }
    }
}


}
```

**STEP 2:- As per the [Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet#android-collect-payment-details) I will get the payment details by performing a server side request**

I perform the server side request from my **`CheckoutVM`** viewmodel using Retrofit in my **`CheckoutRepo`** and return the Checkout Result in a data class called **CheckoutSessionDM**

```
data class CheckoutSessionDM(
val customer: String,
val ephemeralKey: String,
val paymentIntent: String,
val paymentIntentId: String,
val publishableKey: String
)
```

Perform the Network request using Retrofit and update my `CheckoutState` data variable in my ViewModel

```
data class CheckoutState(
val isLoading: Boolean? = null,
val isCompleted: Boolean? = null,
val isCanceled: Boolean? = null,
val isFailed: Boolean? = null,
val paymentSheetResult: PaymentSheetResult? = null,

//Updated after Payment Details are fetched from app API Server
val checkoutSessionDM: CheckoutSessionDM? = null,
val checkoutSessionError: String? = null,
)
```

> NOTE: To get `CheckoutSessionDM` values you need to setup an end-point for
> Stripe on your API server as mentioned in Stripe Documentation for
> [Add-Server-Endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet#add-server-endpoint)

**Making "App API Server" request to get data for `CheckoutSessionDM`** use your own methods to perform the API Request.
I am returning a FLOW to my `CheckoutVM` viewModel from my `CheckoutRepo` as shown below.

> I am using a Resource Class as a Wrapper for my result, you are free
> to use your own method to return the response to your viewmodel and skip this Wrapper class.

Here's the code to my Wrapper class, if anyone wants to use it, place it in a **Resource.kt** file.

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val error: String? = "Unable to display error!"
) {
class Success<T>(data: T?) : Resource<T>(data)
class Error<T>(message: String, data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data, message)
class Loading<T>(val isLoading: Boolean = true) : Resource<T>()
}
```

Calling the API -

```
 suspend fun initPaymentSheet(paymentSheet: PaymentSheet): Flow<Resource<CheckoutSessionDM>>? {

    return flow {

        try {
            val result = api.createSession("100", "INR")

            result?.body()?.run {
                showLog(TAG, "result - $this")

                val checkoutSessionDto = this
                paymentIntentClientSecret = checkoutSessionDto.paymentIntent
                customerConfig = PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration(
                    checkoutSessionDto.customer,
                    checkoutSessionDto.ephemeralKey
                )
                val publishableKey = checkoutSessionDto.publishableKey
                PaymentConfiguration.init(context, publishableKey)

                emit(
                    Resource.Success(
//                    checkoutSessionDto.toCheckoutSessionDM()  // Use a mapper function like this 
//                       or
                        
                        CheckoutSessionDM(
                            customer = checkoutSessionDto.customer,
                            ephemeralKey = checkoutSessionDto.ephemeralKey,
                            paymentIntent = checkoutSessionDto.paymentIntent,
                            paymentIntentId = checkoutSessionDto.paymentIntentId,
                            publishableKey = checkoutSessionDto.publishableKey
                        )
                    )
                )

            } ?: run {
                emit(
                    Resource.Error(
                        data = null,
                        message = "Server Error"
                    )
                )
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            if (e is CancellationException) {
                showLog(TAG, "initPaymentSheet() CancellationException $e")
                throw e
            } else if (e is HttpException) {
                showLog(TAG, "initPaymentSheet() HttpException $e")
            }
            emit(
                Resource.Error(
                    data = null,
                    message = "App Error : $e"
                )
            )
            return@flow
        }
    }

    }
```

> Response from the API is saved in `CheckoutSessionDto` data class
> which is identical to `CheckoutSessionDM`. 2 identical classes are
> used , just to maintain CLEAN Architecture.

**STEP 3:- Presenting the Stripe Payment Sheet**

Once we receive `Resource.Success` in our `getPaymentSessionDetails()` method present in `CheckoutVM`
We are ready to call our `presentPaymentSheet()` method.

It can be called from 2 places

1. **`CheckoutVM`** itself when you receive `Resource.Success` in our `getPaymentSessionDetails()`
2. **`CheckoutScreen`** Composable by observing the value of `CheckoutSessionDM` present in the `CheckoutState` data class.

I've used the 2nd method in my example as shown in **STEP 1**

Inside my `CheckoutScreen` composable I observe the change in value for `CheckoutSessionDM` present in `CheckoutState`
When the `CheckoutSessionDM` becomes non-null, I call `OnCheckOut` event inside my `CheckoutVM` viewModel.

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = checkoutState.value.checkoutSessionDM, block = {
//        If Checkout DM is not null hence the Payment Details are successfully fetched,
//        then show the Stripe Payment Sheet

    checkoutState.value.checkoutSessionDM?.run {
//            Present the Stripe payment sheet
        checkoutVM.onEvent(CheckoutEvent.OnCheckOut(paymentSheet))
    }
})
```

`CheckoutVM` further calls the the `presentPaymentSheet()` method present in my repo class

```
override suspend fun presentPaymentSheet(paymentSheet: PaymentSheet?) {
    paymentSheet?.presentWithPaymentIntent(
        paymentIntentClientSecret,
        PaymentSheet.Configuration(
            merchantDisplayName = "Display Name",
            customer = customerConfig,
            // Set `allowsDelayedPaymentMethods` to true if your business handles
            // delayed notification payment methods like US bank accounts.
            allowsDelayedPaymentMethods = true
        )
    )
}
```

> Lastly, Payment Sheet response can be handled in our callback method `onPaymentSheetResult()` present in `CheckoutVM` viewmodel
>
> or
>
> Inside the `CheckoutScreen` composable using the `LaunchedEffect`
> block for `checkoutState.value.paymentSheetResult`

Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: life saver answer... I'm using `20.29.1`, and I was using the `paymentSheet`  with the `resultCallback` in my composable screen, and I see that is causing re-composing problem infinitely... so I've changed my structure as same as yours, and you saved my whole app's performance...

Comment: I am glad it helped you...hope it was easy to follow and saved some time...

Answer (score 0):

I found setting up an Android Activity and launching from a composable function to be an easy and effective solution that works for many types of third party libraries that launch a sheet or menu. The steps I do to get it to work is
make a file StripePaymentSheetActivity.kt with

```
class StripePaymentSheetActivity(): ComponentActivity() {
    lateinit var paymentSheet: PaymentSheet
    lateinit var customerConfig: PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration
    lateinit var paymentSetupIntentClientSecret: String
    lateinit var paymentIntentClientSecret: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        paymentSheet = PaymentSheet(this, ::onPaymentSheetResult)
        // you can retrieve strings from jetpack compose with putExtra
        val customerId = getIntent().getStringExtra("customerId")
        // you need to make a server call here to get your clientSecret
        // and ephemeralKey here
        resp = YourServerRequestToGetClientSecretAndEpheralKeyHere()

        // secret will be in the form seti_*****
        paymentSetupIntentClientSecret = resp.clientSecret
        // Switch for making a payment and will be in the form pi_****
        // paymentIntentClientSecret = resp.clientSecret
        customerConfig = PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration(
            id = customerId,
            ephemeralKeySecret = resp.ephemeralKey,
        )
        // publishableKey is your pk_test or pk_live key you find on stripe
        PaymentConfiguration.init(this, publishableKey)
        // this where it is a little different from the stipe documentation.
        // This method onCreate will be hit once we launch the activity but 
        // there is no way to call a function after launching an activity
        // in compose so we will just do it when this is activity is created.
        presentPaymentSheet()
    }

    fun onPaymentSheetResult(paymentSheetResult: PaymentSheetResult) {
        Log.d("PaymentSheet", "PaymentSheet result: $paymentSheetResult")
        when(paymentSheetResult) {
            is PaymentSheetResult.Canceled -> {
                // this registers the callback into the compose function
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED)
                finish()
            }
            is PaymentSheetResult.Failed -> {
                // this registers the callback into the compose function
                setResult(RESULT_ERROR)
                finish()
            }
            is PaymentSheetResult.Completed -> {
                // this registers the callback into the compose function
                setResult(RESULT_OK)
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    fun presentPaymentSheet() {
        // this is for storing payment methods like when you
        // have an app that has continuous payments like Uber. 
        paymentSheet.presentWithSetupIntent(
            paymentSetupIntentClientSecret,
            PaymentSheet.Configuration(
                merchantDisplayName = "Your Merchant Name",
                customer = customerConfig,
                // Set `allowsDelayedPaymentMethods` to true if your business
                // can handle payment methods that complete payment after a delay, like SEPA Debit and Sofort.
                allowsDelayedPaymentMethods = true
            )
        )
        // or you can use this with a payment intent
//        paymentSheet.presentWithPaymentIntent(
//            paymentIntentClientSecret,
//            PaymentSheet.Configuration(
//                merchantDisplayName = "Your Company Name",
//                customer = customerConfig,
//                allowsDelayedPaymentMethods = true
//            )
//        )
    }

    override public fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

Then from your compose function add

```
@Composable
fun YourComposeFunctionHere(){
    var intent = Intent(user.context, StripePaymentSheetActivity::class.java)
    // you can send strings into your activity with something like this
    // customer id should be in the form of cus_*****
    intent.putExtra("customerId", customerId)

    // make an activity launcher that has a callback for when the activity
    // has a result ready
    val stripeLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ){  result: ActivityResult  ->
        if(result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             // do what you need to do if its ok
        }else if(result.resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
             // do what you need to do if its canceled 
        }else if(result.resultCode == RESULT_ERROR){
             // do what you need to do if its canceled 
        }else{
             // you shouldn't get here
        }
    }
    // GUI Code here
        TextButton(
            // this will launch StripePaymentSheetActivity
            // and then the method onCreate will run presentPaymentSheet()
            onClick = { stripeLauncher.launch(intent) },
            ),
        ) {
            Text(text = "Pay")
        }

}
```

Finally add your activity to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity android:name="com.example.myapplication.StripePaymentSheetActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" />
```

Note you will need to add your specific path to StripePaymentSheetActivity.kt

This method allows you to stay extremely close to the recommended stripe documents and also is a great structure for launching other activities like a Facebook login view or a Braintree paymentsheet.