# Stripe Integration with Jetpack Compose

Tags: stripe-payments, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement a Stripe payment sheet within Jetpack Compose. However, it appears as if Stripe doesn't have integration with Jetpack Compose. Am I incorrect in this assumption? If so, how can I implement a payment sheet using out-of-the-box Stripe functionality? If not, is there any sense of when Stripe will release Jetpack Compose integration? I saw that Stripe has had this development on their backlog since at least 2021.

My code currently utilizes `PaymentLauncher.rememberLauncher` to confirm user payment and handle the payment result. However, it doesn't include functionality for the user to input payment details, so I'm currently hardcoding one of Stripe's test cards for testing purposes.

Note that my question differs from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74634644/stripe-payment-api-integration-to-jetpack-compose) because the latter focuses on payment confirmation. That is, it pinpoints how to utilize Stripe in Compose to process payments *given that the payment information is known*. The crux of my question is about integrating a pre-built Stripe component that allows users to easily input payment information.

Comment: You need to pass or remember reference to the object relevant to the Stripe (such as the PaymentLauncher), you can utilize CompositionalLocalProiders. Integration itself requires only an Activity, it's not necessarily bound to the View or Composable. 

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet#android-flowcontroller

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I'm not sure what you mean by utilizing CompositionLocalProvider. Also, how would one use an Activity within a Jetpack Compose application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stripe Payment API integration to Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74634644/stripe-payment-api-integration-to-jetpack-compose)

Comment: @orakaro Unfortunately, no. That thread gives a partial solution, since it shares how to confirm payment via Stripe within Compose. However, it doesn't communicate how one would create a user-friendly payment sheet with pre-built Stripe components within Compose.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Stripe SDK version "20.26.0", they have provided a dedicated method to generate instance of `PaymentSheet` **inside a composable**.

Here's how -

```
val paymentSheet =
    rememberPaymentSheet(paymentResultCallback = yourViewModel::onPaymentSheetResult)
```

The callback method `onPaymentSheetResult()` can be created inside your ViewModel to handle the response.

I've given a detailed answer from initalization to result on this question - [Stripe Payment API integration to Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77221365/11223209)

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by `include functionality for the user to input payment details` ? Or you are looking for a way to integrating [CardInputWidget](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/payments-core/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/view/CardInputWidget.kt) through Compose?

Comment: Yes, I mean something along the lines of integrating CardInputWidget via Compose.

Comment: The CardInputWidget is still view-based and not a Composable yet. You might want to wrap it with AndroidView (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose) and make it Composable.

Comment: Got it. I'll go with that approach for now. Any idea on Stripe's timeline for making CardInputWidget a Composable?

Comment: I don't know the timeline but you can submit your feature request at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues