# Stripe Setup API Performance Issue in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, stripe-payments, android-jetpack-compose

The animation that displays the Stripe view is choppy/jittery and very noticeable.

I've implemented Stripe using Compose, with the help of this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75047550/22049336.

Using this Stripe dependency: `implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.21.1'`

```
@Compose
fun stripePaymentLauncher(clientSecret: String, onResult: () -> Unit = {}) {
    val stripeLauncher =
    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = PaymentSheetContract()) { result ->
      viewModel.handlePaymentResult(result)
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = clientSecret) {
      if (clientSecret.isNotEmpty()) {
        val args = PaymentSheetContract.Args.createSetupIntentArgs(clientSecret)
        stripeLauncher.launch(args)
      }
    }
}
```

Using the Layout Inspector I didn't detect any multiple recompositions that could have been causing it. I wondering if this is an issue I can resolve on my end.

Comment: How do you use this composable? It seems its parameters do not change so recompositions won't acquire. You should change the state of the composable (i.e. by passing a new clientSecret or implementing it as same as the example you provided) so a recomposition can acquire.

Comment: +1 to above. How exactly are you using the composable? I believe there's an example from Stripe dev here on how you can use PaymentSheet with compose

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/3803

Comment: So in my main @Composable screen I have `val clientSecret by viewModel.stripeClientSecret.observeAsState("")` that, when the value changes calls `stripePaymentLauncher()`. When I debug the `stripeLauncher.launch(args)` only gets called once.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are trying to integrate payment using Braintree. If you're open to another alternative, Stripe offers a robust SDK that you can integrate into Android, especially if you're using Jetpack Compose.

Firstly, ensure you have these dependencies in your build.gradle:

```
//Stripe Library
implementation("com.stripe:stripe-android:20.28.3")
```

If you're planning on using Dagger Hilt for dependency injection:

```
//Dagger Hilt for DI
  def dagger_hilt_version = "2.47"
  implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt- 
  android:$dagger_hilt_version"
  annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt- 
  compiler:$dagger_hilt_version"
  kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$dagger_hilt_version"
  kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
  implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0"
  kapt 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.7.0'
```

> To integrate Stripe, follow these steps:

1. **Initialize Stripe:**

You need to set up the PaymentConfiguration in your custom Application class.

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication: Application() {
  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    PaymentConfiguration.init(applicationContext, Info.stripePublisherKey)
  }
}
```

2. **Info File**:

this is a info file in project.

```
 class Info {
      companion object{
          const val url = "https://api.stripe.com/"
          const val stripePublisherKey = "add_your_publish_key"
          const val stripeSecretKey = "add_your_secret_key"
      }
 }
```

3. **Stripe Screen:**

You can design a Composable function, say StripeScreen, that will have buttons and logic to trigger different operations like creating customers, fetching ephemeral keys, creating payment intents, and finally, making the payment.

```
@Composable
fun StripeScreen(navController: NavHostController, viewModel: StripeViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val customer by viewModel.customer.collectAsState()
    val ephemeralKey by viewModel.ephemeralKey.collectAsState()
    val paymentIntent by viewModel.paymentIntent.collectAsState()
    val error by viewModel.error.collectAsState()

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val stripeLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = PaymentSheetContract(),
        onResult = {
            viewModel.handlePaymentResult(context, it)
        }
    )

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(title = { Text(text = "Payment Screen") })
        },
    ){
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(it),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(text = "Customer ID: ${customer?.id ?: "Not fetched"}")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

            Text(text = "Ephemeral Key ID: ${ephemeralKey?.id ?: "Not fetched"}")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

            Text(text = "Payment Intent ID: ${paymentIntent?.client_secret ?: "Not fetched"}")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

            if (error != null) {
                Text(text = "Error: $error", color = MaterialTheme.colors.error)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            }

            Button(onClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    viewModel.createCustomer()
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "Create Customer")
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

            Button(onClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    customer?.id?.let { viewModel.fetchEphemeralKey(it) }
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "Fetch Ephemeral Key")
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

            Button(onClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    customer?.id?.let {id ->
                        viewModel.createPaymentIntent(id)
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "Create Payment Intent")
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

            Button(onClick = {
                paymentIntent?.client_secret?.let { clientSecret ->
                    val args = PaymentSheetContract.Args.createPaymentIntentArgs(clientSecret)
                    stripeLauncher.launch(args)
                }

            }) {
                Text(text = "Open Stripe PaymentSheet")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. **Create a ViewModel:**

For handling your payment operations, you can utilize a ViewModel. Here's a sample StripeViewModel which includes functions to create customers, fetch ephemeral keys, create payment intents, and handle payment results:

```
@HiltViewModel
class StripeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val stripeRepository: StripeRepository) : ViewModel() {

    // Mutable versions
    private val _customer = MutableStateFlow<CustomerApiModel?>(null)
    private val _ephemeralKey = MutableStateFlow<EphemeralKeyApiModel?>(null)
    private val _paymentIntent = MutableStateFlow<PaymentIntentApiModel?>(null)

    // Exposed as read-only StateFlow
    val customer: StateFlow<CustomerApiModel?> = _customer
    val ephemeralKey: StateFlow<EphemeralKeyApiModel?> = _ephemeralKey
    val paymentIntent: StateFlow<PaymentIntentApiModel?> = _paymentIntent

    private val _error = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    val error: StateFlow<String?> = _error

    fun createCustomer() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val response = stripeRepository.createCustomer()
                _customer.emit(response)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Log the exception or provide user feedback
                _error.emit(e.message)
            }
        }
    }

    fun fetchEphemeralKey(customerId: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val response = stripeRepository.createEphemeralKey(customerId)
                _ephemeralKey.emit(response)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Log the exception or provide user feedback
                _error.emit(e.message)
            }
        }
    }

    fun createPaymentIntent(
        customerId: String,
        amount: Int = 10000,
        currency: String = "usd",
        autoPaymentMethodsEnable: Boolean = true
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val response = stripeRepository.createPaymentIntent(
                    customerId,
                    amount,
                    currency,
                    autoPaymentMethodsEnable
                )
                _paymentIntent.emit(response)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Log the exception or provide user feedback
                _error.emit(e.message)
            }
        }
    }

    fun handlePaymentResult(context: Context, result: PaymentSheetResult) {
        when (result) {
            PaymentSheetResult.Canceled -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Payment Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            PaymentSheetResult.Completed -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Payment Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            is PaymentSheetResult.Failed -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "${result.error}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.e("Payment Error", result.error.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

5. **Repository:**

A repository class, StripeRepository, can abstract the API calls and provide an interface for the ViewModel to fetch or send data.

```
    class StripeRepository @Inject constructor(private val apiService: StripeApiService) {

    suspend fun createCustomer(): CustomerApiModel {
        return apiService.createCustomer()
    }

    suspend fun createEphemeralKey(customerId: String): EphemeralKeyApiModel {
        return apiService.createEphemeralKey(customerId)
    }

    suspend fun createPaymentIntent(
        customerId: String,
        amount: Int,
        currency: String,
        autoPaymentMethodsEnable: Boolean
    ): PaymentIntentApiModel {
        return apiService.createPaymentIntent(
            customerId,
            amount,
            currency,
            autoPaymentMethodsEnable
        )
    }
}
```

5. **API Service:**

Retrofit can be used to interact with Stripe API. The key headers and API calls can be set up as follows:

```
interface StripeApiService {
    @Headers(
        "Authorization: Bearer $SECRET",
        "Stripe-Version: 2022-11-15"
    )
    @POST("v1/customers")
    suspend fun createCustomer() : CustomerApiModel

    @Headers(
        "Authorization: Bearer $SECRET",
        "Stripe-Version: 2022-11-15"
    )
    @POST("v1/ephemeral_keys")
    suspend fun createEphemeralKey(
        @Query("customer") customerId: String
    ): EphemeralKeyApiModel

    @Headers(
        "Authorization: Bearer $SECRET"
    )
    @POST("v1/payment_intents")
    suspend fun createPaymentIntent(
        @Query("customer") customerId: String,
        @Query("amount") amount: Int,
        @Query("currency") currency: String,
        @Query("automatic_payment_methods[enabled]") autoPaymentMethodsEnable: Boolean,
    ): PaymentIntentApiModel

}
```

6. **Data Models:**

These are Kotlin data classes which will help in parsing the API response:

```
    data class CustomerApiModel(
    val id: String,
    val email: String?,
    val created: Long
)


data class EphemeralKeyApiModel(
    val id: String,
    val created: Long,
    val expires: Long,
    val secret: String,
    val associated_objects: List<AssociatedObject>
)

data class AssociatedObject(
    val id: String,
    val type: String
)

data class PaymentIntentApiModel(
    val id: String,
    val amount: Int,
    val currency: String,
    val created: Long,
    val status: String,
    val client_secret: String?
)
```

7. **Dependency Injection:**

Use Dagger Hilt to inject dependencies. The MainModule object provides essential objects such as the Stripe instance and the StripeRepository.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object MainModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideStripe(@ApplicationContext context: Context): Stripe {
        return Stripe(context, Info.stripePublisherKey)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideStripeApiService(): StripeApiService {
        return NetworkModule.stripeApiService
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providePaymentRepository(stripeApiService: StripeApiService): StripeRepository {
        return StripeRepository(stripeApiService)
    }
}
```

For a more comprehensive guide and complete codebase, you can check out this repository: https://github.com/Harash1421/payment_integration.